# JsRoutingBundle and Ajax in symfony2.8

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

i have a problem with my ajax call in symfony:

here is my ajax call :

```
var route = Routing.generate('bien_index', {'id' : id});

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: route+"",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    });
    }
```

and here is my controller action :

```
public function indexAction(Bien $bien)
{
    return new Response($bien,200);}
```

can any one tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: what kind of error? You see it in the browser console? can you post that error?

Comment: check the route is exposed with the command described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/commands.html#fos-js-routing-debug)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add in your routing.yml

```
bien_index:
    options:
        expose: true
```